# Create a pd.DataFrame with a minimum number of rows using hypothesis

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I'm using the `hypothesis` library and I would like to create a `pd.DataFrame` with three columns. Each column may contain integer values, either +1, 0, or -1. The values doesn't need to be unique. Also, I would like to get at least ten rows.

With the following code, `hypothesis` seems to produce either empty dataframes or a dataframe with only one row.
When adding `assume(len(signals) > 10)` to the test, `hypothesis` is not able to find a suitable example.

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns, data_frames

@given(
    signals=data_frames(
        columns=columns(
            ["sec_1", "sec_2", "sec_3"],
            elements=st.integers(min_value=-1, max_value=1),
        )
    )
)
def test_length(signals: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    assume(len(signals) > 10)
    assert len(signals) > 10
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying the minimum size of the index, which you can fix with e.g.: [`dataframes(columns=..., index=range_indexes(min_size=10))`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html#hypothesis.extra.pandas.range_indexes).

(and I'd guess you're failing with a health check that rejection sampling is quite inefficient here)